# Barcode Scanner, data shows if scanning twice

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, barcode, barcode-scanner

i have this code,

```
try{
    var scanner = cordova.require("com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner");    
    scanner.scan ( function(result) {
        var xxx = result.text;
        {dialog.Object}.setValue('barcode_result',xxx);
        }, function(error){
            navigator.notification.alert("scanning failes:"+error);
        });
} catch(e){
    navigator.notification.alert('scanner error : '+e)
}
```

The problem is barcode can be read after  I do scan it twice.

thanks